# What is "val$title" (dollar sign in expression) in Java?

Tags: java, swing

```
private void launchEventPanel(String title) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(title) {
        public void run() {
            JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
            myFrame.setTitle(this.val$title);
            myFrame.setIconImage(CrConference.this.mainCore.myPanel.myIconManager.getPromptIcon(Mart.class.toString()));
            myFrame.getContentPane().add(Conference.this.myEventPanel, "Center");
            myFrame.pack();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

i got some code that i am trying to compile and understand. help highly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475/valid-characters-in-a-java-class-name , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845299/why-is-it-bad-to-start-a-variable-name-with-a-dollar-sign-in-c-java-and-simila , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987603/is-there-a-convention-when-using-java-rmi-to-use-the-dollar-sign-in-a-variab

Comment: Is this decompiled code? I would expect variable names like that in decompiled code.

Comment: I have edited the title to reflect the "odd code", `val$title` a perfectly valid Java identifier -- it's just as valid as `foobar` -- but the "rule" is to not use it (except tools that generate code automatically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
myFrame.setTitle(this.val$title);
```

Is simply setting the title of a `JFrame` object, using the value of the attribute `val$title` for doing so. `val$title` is an instance attribute of the current class, its name is a bit unusual (because of the `$`) but nevertheless, valid for an identifier in Java.

Comment: It could be a local variable :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad no local variables with that name are declared in the code in the question

Comment: @user1315911 you're welcome! if this answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it (click the check mark to its left)

Comment: Never knew `$` was a valid identifier in Java, phew

Answer (score 4):

As described [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/238605-decompiled-java-code-val-fix/page__view__findpost__p__1723899?s=db3843f9efe50a397d66c26812a5e0f4) and [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/A-tip-on-val%24-field-in-Java-decompiled-code-1725.php), the argument to the `Runnable` constuctor and "this.val$" to the field name is added by the compiler and shows up in the generated bytecode. Hence these extra things are reflected in the decompiled code.

To get the original decompiled code, add `final` to the declaration of `title` and remove `title` from the call to `Runnable` and the `this.val$` from in front of `title`:

```
private void launchEventPanel(final String title) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
            myFrame.setTitle(title);
            myFrame.setIconImage(CrConference.this.mainCore.myPanel.myIconManager.getPromptIcon(Mart.class.toString()));
            myFrame.getContentPane().add(Conference.this.myEventPanel, "Center");
            myFrame.pack();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

line 5 is just setting the title of the frame (the text you see on the top of the window frame in windows) "this.val$title" is just a local memeber named val$title that whoever wrote the code stored the title string in.

While it is a bit uncommon to see most languages based on C treat $ as an alphapetic character, like a-z or A-Z.

Comment: Languages *loosely* based on C, or that use C-like *syntax*, maybe.  C itself doesn't, nor does C++ AFAIK.  JS and Java are the only C-alikes i can think of of that do, actually.